# Factorized trace of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are there any particular types of matrices for which: $tr(AB)=tr(A)tr(B)$.

Comment: $1\times 1$ matrices?

Comment: Thanks, are there any other classes?

Comment: Yes, such as the set of all upper triangular matrices with zero diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

$$tr(AB)=tr(A)tr(B)$$
$$\Sigma_{j,i} a_{ji} b_{ij}=\Sigma_{j,i} a_{jj} b_{ii}$$

$$\Sigma_{j,i} a_{ji} b_{ij} - a_{jj} b_{ii}=0$$

From here I am trying to find a class of matrices. To start with, let us assume that we are dealing with diagonal matrices only.

$$\Sigma_{j,i} a_{ji} b_{ij} \delta_{ij} - a_{jj} b_{ii}=0$$

For 2x2 matrices:

$$a_{11} b_{11} +  a_{22} b_{22} - (a_{11} + a_{22})(b_{11} + b_{22})=0$$
$$-a_{11} b_{22} -  a_{22} b_{11} =0$$
$$-a_{11} b_{22} = a_{22} b_{11}$$